# htaccess line resolves in error 500

Tags: .htaccess

For some strange reason the below .htaccess doesn't work and resolves in an Internal Error 500 message. Does anyone have a clue? I'm clueless... When I only put 'RewriteEngine On' no problems happen, when I type another line I get the error. Even when I type everything on one single line (to check if whitespace is not ignored, the same happens).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will cause an infinite loop, because it also matches /index.php.

Try:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]`

If that doesn't do it add a RewriteCond which specifies anything but `^/index.php$`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion did the trick! I also added another condition to exclude all css, js and images. Thanks again, +1 + accepted:)